# in ASP.NET MVC3 how can I see the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest

I'm using a simple route as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default2", // Route name
    "{cliurl}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { cliurl = "none", controller = "ABook", action = "Index", id = "none" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{cliurl}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { cliurl = "none", controller = "ABook", action = "Index", id = "none" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and when I debug the website (VS2010 SP1), I have a breakpoint in my `ABook` Controller, inside the `Index` action method witch contains only:

```
//
// GET: /ABook/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (currentClient == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Empty");

    return View();
}

//
// GET: /Empty/
public ActionResult Empty()
{
    return View();
}
```

The thing is that, when I insert this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:14951/client_name/hashed_id
```

I get **3 breaks in that breakpoint**.

How can I see what in the world is going on? why 3 times when I just requested 1, what is exactly the browser requesting?

I can only get the Route Parameters and I do get the first correct, but 2nd and 3rd are using the default values, and I tried to navigate through the `RequestContext` and I can't see anything useful :(

> Just want to know if there is a way to really see what's been requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)

> http://getglimpse.com/

http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2011-05-28_1854.png

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how do you download it? I got here- http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Glimpse and no link..

Comment: Install `NuGet` in `Visual Studio` (if you have MVC3 templates) you already have it. Right Click in the References folder in your project, and select **Add Library Package Reference**, click `Online` -> `NuGet official package source` and search for `Glimpse` ... install! - You can get the dialog from **Tools** -> **Library Package Manager** -> **Add Library Package Reference...**, or open the Console and install using `Install-Package Glimpse` - Read more here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx

Comment: Also you can go to codeplex now and download it directly - http://glimpse.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have breakpoint inside controller you can use watch where you can simply create new watch. Type in `Request` and search it...

Comment: I know how to use the Visual Studio Tools, that is not my question, I just want to know where can I see it, what object, as `RequestContext` object contains nothing about it.

Comment: What has been requsted is in `Request` object

Answer (score 1):

In every Controller there exists a property called **Request**. It is actually defined in System.Web.Mvc.Controller which is the superclass of all controllers. The property returns the acutal Request object as HttpRequestBase and exposes fields like InputStream, Headers, HttpMethod so on and so forth.

As for why you are hitting the index method 3 times, I'm sure that other requests made by the browser, say for example for images and javascript and other existing files, also are handled by your route defined. In short your route defenition is too generic and handles unexpected requests. You can correct this by using Route.IgnoreRoute("Path/to/Existing/Files") or by making your route more specific by adding RouteConstraints. Leave a comment if you want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the browser requests or you could try the `routdebugger` download from Nuget.

Comment: :o) I know that one, I want to know inside the code, the flow, the requests that are inside MVC

Answer (score 0):

I know others have sort-of made a stab at this... they are correct:

Use the `Request` object to find out what is being requested. It's probably something incorrectly being handled by your controller. Shovel some output while debugging from `Request` in that method, such as the raw url. That will likely answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, why not hook up the `BeginRequest` event handler for the application which will allow you to see every request coming through. There is also the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` object which can be inspected

```
    // Global.asax
    public MvcApplication()
    {
        BeginRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_BeginRequest);
    }

    void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("[Start] Requested Url: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
```